# Como hago para que no se sobre escriba el valor en un textView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy tratando de hacer que al presionar los botones no se borren o sobre escriban el valor, ejemplo: Si presiono el botón A que se muestre en el textview la letra A y luego si presiono el botón B también que se muestre pero sin eliminar la letra A y si presiono otra tecla cual sea el valor  siempre se agregue al textView sin borrar las demas letras: ABCDEFRGLA532.
Por ahora tengo 3 botones pero cada vez que presiono uno borra al anterior :
codigo: JAVA

```
TextView MostrarNombre;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btnBorrar, btnCopiar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MostrarNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mNombre);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btnCopiar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCopiar);
    btnBorrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrar);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String a = btn1.getText().toString();
            MostrarNombre.setText(a);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String b = btn2.getText().toString();
            MostrarNombre.setText(b);
        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String c = btn3.getText().toString();
            MostrarNombre.setText(c);
        }
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String d = btn4.getText().toString();
            MostrarNombre.setText(d);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Espero de su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que requieres es que se agregue al final del texto, puedes usar el metodo getText() para obtener el valor actual de tu textView y luego agregas o concatenas el caracter.

Asi:

```
MostrarNombre.setText(MostrarNombre.getText() + a);
```

Tendrias que modificar en el codigo de cada boton.

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo lo que quería. Saludooooos